# Issues when printing values with Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm working on simple app and I decided to use Laravel 5.4 and Vue.js.
When I want to print something in vue.js I use "`{{message}}`" code like this.

But it throws an exception in php (Laravel)

In Laravel `{{ }}` also uses to print.

`{{}} = <?php echo ''; ?>`

Is it possible and is there a way to change `{{}}` identifier to `(())`
In Laravel or Vue.js?

Answer (score 6):

You can tell Laravel to ignore mustaches templating since Vue use it by putting `@` in front of expression

```
@{{ message }}
```

This would be ignored by Laravel.

Also, you can change delimiters in VueJS - check docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Comment: This is also the (Laravel) documented way to ignore handlebars.